# Create an Exception for single object active effect in CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using the class `media-body` with an effect:

```
.media-body:active{ background-color: #EEEEEE;}
```

on many objects in my application. But on a particular page i need to put this effect on two seperate elemnts inside the `"media-body"` Object.
So is it possible to set an exception or are there better way's to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.media-body selector:active{ background-color: #EEEEEE;}`
**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8q4bx9f2/1/)**